# MVC delivering content when views folder is in the wrong place, how is this possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, directory-structure

So, I have an MVC4 application.  I must have been having slippery fingers yesterday, because on our production server I mistakenly moved the views folder to the /Content folder.  Everything stopped working and I couldn't figure out why (I have a custom error page, which wasn't getting hit and I was just getting the generic IIS error page).  After manually changing web.config to see the error I realized it wasn't finding the login view, found the view folders and moved it back, everything's great.

Here's the weird part.  At first, I thought it might be a database problem so I rebooted Sql Server, and everything started working.  Then later when I actually found the problem, it started erroring again.  Anyways, just wondering if anybody has any ideas who it was working in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a "fresh" deployment -- delete and re-publish all the files?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't getting HTTP-cached versions of your page? Or does "everything started working" mean you could log in and use the site as normal?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not cached.  I did some database updates that were getting correctly populated on the page.  However, my users were saying the problem seemed to happen after they updated a record.  As to a fresh deploy, I'm going to do that now and just keep an eye on it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you published you site using Visual Studio's Publish Web functionality, you may have left the "Leave extra files on destination (do not delete)" checkbox ticked. You can confirm this in the Publish Profile dialog in VS.

If this is checked, files remain on the destination in their original location even if you move or delete them.

So in your case (if the checkbox was ticked), if you accidentally moved the views folder in VS, then published to your webserver with the views in the wrong place, then the original copies would remain.

It is not clear from your question how you moved the files though. If you moved the views on the webserver itself, then this would not apply, it only applies if you made the move occur by changing their location in VS, then publishing the change..

Comment: I do always deploy as deleting all files on the destination first.  As to moving the Views folder, I do not know for certain that I did this but that's a theory.  After I publish I connect to the site via ftp to manually upload some license files, and this is when I think I might have moved the folder.

Comment: Well I am out of ideas, I suggested this to you as it has happened to me before. I couldn't work out why my view was still displaying and it was only when I realised the view was a really old version and must not been deleted that led me to the reason it was happening.

Comment: So, it turns out there was an issue with the servers where I host my stie.  Apparently the web server farm was was having problems and not distributing things correctly.

Comment: Ah well, thats from left field! Glad you found the problem :)